# For what values of $b\in \mathbb R$ is $\pi-b$ rational?

Tags: pi, rationality-testing

Just a simple short question.
I'm looking for values $b$ such that $\pi-b$ is a rational number. 
Obviously $\pi$ is such a number, but are there more?

Edit: $b$ is in $\mathbb R$

Comment: Every number of the form $\pi+r$ with $r\in\Bbb Q$ has this property, and these are the only numbers that do.

Comment: and they are not easier to classify in any other way then just saying that $\pi-b\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why there aren't any more such numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, and almost vacuously $b=\pi+q$ for some rational number $q$. You can easily show that these are the only ones.

Comment: Why aren't there more? Like I know that $b=\pi+r$ where $r$ is rational is true. But how can I show that there aren't more?

Comment: Oria, suppose $b$ is such that $\pi-b=q\in\Bbb Q$, then $b=\pi-q$.

Comment: Obviously...It's late :D Thanks as always Asaf.

Comment: Late by what standard? :-)

Comment: Meaning she should go to sleep and stop doing math for a while.

Comment: @user4140: She? Do you know Oria personally?

Comment: Considering he got the gender wrong, I'd guess he doesn't...thanks Asaf. Will accept the answer. I feel ashamed asking this question even.

Comment: @Oria: Well, Oria is not a common name for a girl in our area, after all. :-)

Comment: Oh, sorry about that.

Comment: I think it is important to highlight in the answer that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field. So you and add and subtract rational numbers and have a rational number as its result. So since $\pi$ is rational, assume b is rational, then $\pi - b \in \Bbb{Q}$, reciprocally if $\pi - b = q \in \Bbb{Q}$ for some $b \in \Bbb{R}$ then $b = \pi -  q$ and $b \in \Bbb{Q}$ because $\Bbb{Q}$ is a field. So it's a "if and only if" situation.